# Add product to cart with my custom price based on product detail page fields input from customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to get 3 Fields from user to be filled with custom size and after that based on that size need to generate a price against it. That price I can show on page but when adding to Cart, It's original price of the product

I used This code with Observer method

[image: This is Observer]

```
class CustomPrice implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        // here i am using item's product final price
        $price = 1000; // 10 is custom price. It will increase in product price.
        // Set the custom price
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        // Enable super mode on the product.
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        return $this;
    }

}
```

[image: This is the Events.xml file]

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_update_items_after">
    <observer name="customprice" instance="MGS\CartPrice\Observer\CustomPrice" />
</event>
```

I adopted code from https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-set-custom-price-of-product/

Comment: Please put the code into text, not an image.

Comment: I edited code for both Observer.php and events.xml file